# Add a column to query result that shows the no of successful comparisons of the keys in the CONTAINS clasue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT * from table1 where 
CONTAINS(column,'key1 OR key2 OR key3')
```

Now i want to add another column which contains the number of the keys(key1,key2,key3) found in that row(either 1,2 or 3).How do i do that? I don't want to use 'containstable' or freetexttable as i will making my own ranking function once i get the no of keys matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of keys that match easily enough:

```
select *,
  case when Contains( Column, 'key1' ) then 1 else 0 end +
  case when Contains( Column, 'key2' ) then 1 else 0 end +
  case when Contains( Column, 'key3' ) then 1 else 0 end as [NumberOfMatchingKeys]
  from Table1
  where Contains( column, 'key1 OR key2 OR key3' )
```

What you can't get, at least easily, is the number of matches for any given key.  Finding out that *key2* matched 7 times is a problem.

A possible optimization is to remove the `Contains` from the `where` clause:

```
select * from (
  select *,
    case when Contains( Column, 'key1' ) then 1 else 0 end +
    case when Contains( Column, 'key2' ) then 1 else 0 end +
    case when Contains( Column, 'key3' ) then 1 else 0 end as [NumberOfMatchingKeys]
    from Table1 ) as Louise
 where NumberOfMatchingKeys > 0
```

Comment: `select *,case when contains( keyword, 'key1' ) then 1 else 0 end as [Key1],case when Contains( keyword, 'key2' ) then 1 else 0 end as [Key2],case when Contains( keyword, 'key3' ) then 1 else 0 end as [Key3],case when Contains( keyword, 'background' ) then 1 else 0 end  as [MatchingKeys] from table1` gives me the no of matches for any key. Your optimized solution looks good too. I will probably use it if i dont have to give weighted ranks to each key successfully matched. I already edited your solution to include my solution.

Comment: peer review on stackoverflow sucks..if you want you can edit your post to include my solution as well.

Comment: @thunderbird - If you change the `1`'s that are being added to powers of 2 (1, 2, 4, ...) then the sum will be a bitmask indicating which, if any, of the keys matched.  You can do the simple test against zero to see if any matched, or `BitMask & 4 > 0` to see if the third key matched.  Combinations are also possible, e.g. `BitMask & 7 > 0` is true if any of the first three keys matched.

Comment: yes i can probably do that but would that be more efficient than making a separate column for each key being searched?@HABO

Comment: @thunderbird - That would depend on how much data you have and how you use it.  There is some overhead associated with each column.  If you are mostly checking for _any_ match then combining the bits into one column should help.  If you are fiddling around more with applying weights to individual keys it may not help.  You could change the multipliers from powers of 2 to weighting factors, but that would preclude you from picking the keys back out of the sum.  Premature optimization is a bad thing.  Run some tests with your data and look at some execution plans to see what you get.

Comment: thx a lot for the help..using a single column with bits looks more convenient and efficient. i can always apply the weights later on on my server side code.